# SDL_VIDEORESIZE doesn't work

Tags: c++, resize, sdl

I have a SDL application and want to make the window resizable. So I put proper flag in SDL_SetVideoMode() and made an event handler. But when I resize window, handler isn't activated. I don't know why.

Code of my event loop:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent (&event));
{
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        return 0+1;
    else if (event.type == SDL_VIDEORESIZE)
    {
        board.x = static_cast<int> ( static_cast<float> (event.resize.w - 2 * hMargin) / Field + 0.5f );
        board.y = static_cast<int> ( static_cast<float> (event.resize.h - 2 * vMargin - Face - FaceSpace) / Field + 0.5f );
        return 0;
    }
}
```

return 0+1 is for successful exit (main returns 0); return 0 is for restarting app (doing another SetVideoMode).

It looks like when I resize window, the event is not sent.

I'm using SDL version 1.2.14.

EDIT:

I wrote a sample program, and it worked. But I've looked once more at the code and... seen a semicolon after while() -.-

Comment: Can you post a complete, minimal SDL program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yep, seems that ";" is the guilt :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you can just call SDL_SetVideoMode() without quitting SDL to resize
2. ; after the while as Diego Sevilla has noticed
3. There is a option to create a automatic re-sizable screen just in case you did not know

http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_SetVideoMode
says everything